# how to use multiple optional arguements in find() pymong

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to create a function that makes use of pymongos find function,but with user parameter.

```
class ServiceLog(Document):
    # session_id = sessionStart.pk
    creation_date = DateTimeField(required=True)
    log_level = StringField(required=True)
    tag = StringField(required=True)
    message = StringField(required=True)
    db.service_log.ensure_index(u'log_level', 1)
    db.service_log.ensure_index(u'tag', 1)


    def log(self, logLevel, taG, messagE, sid):
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
        time = asctime()
        ServiceLog(creation_date=time,
                   log_level=logLevel,
                   tag=taG,
                   message=messagE,
                   session_id=sid).save()

    def listLog(self, logLevel, taG, messagE, sid, lim_num, sk_num):
        db.log.find(creation_date=time,
                    log_level=logLevel,
                    tag=taG,
                    message=messagE,
                    session_id=sid).skip(sk_num).limit(lim_num)
```

How can i change the listLog so the user can input any number of parameters that will match?

Comment: excuse me, what is `Document`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `**kwargs`, with a little tweaking.

For example:

```
def listLog(self, sk_num=0, lim_num=0, **kwargs):
    db.log.find(kwargs).skip(sk_num).limit(lim_num)
```

This code does the following:

1. Defines a method with two optional parameters which have default values: sk_num and lim_num.
2. The `**kwargs` is shorthand for "take as many extra keyword arguments as you want, and place them into a dict called kwargs". [Read up on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs).
3. It is using the kwargs dict as the search query in mongodb's find(). This means that the values of the arguments passed into the function must be safe and valid mongo query options.

You would have to change the names of your parameters to match the names of the MongoDB document entries. So rather than naming your method param `logLevel`, you'd name it `log_level` to match the collection.